# CSS opacity + resize causing image to repeat on firefox 37

Tags: css, firefox, opacity

I've got an annoying issue on Firefox 37.0.2 whenever I use the CSS opacity affecting images or background images. 
It causes one image to be repeated instead of displaying the other images. 
I don't know if I'm clear but I couldn't find any discussion about it online.

Obviously I've noticed this behaviour on many websites since the problem is very basic, so I'm guessing it only affects me somehow (could be specific addons or settings?) but I had to make sure and ask you.

Here's a fiddle about it: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qk743u2/)

```
<div class="a">
<div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div>
<div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/401/400" /></div>
...
</div>

<div class="b"><!-- test div without opacity -->
<div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" /></div>
<div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/401/400" /></div>
...
</div>
```

The css:

```
div div{
    width:20%;
    float:left    
}
div div img{
    width:100%;    
}
div.a div img{
    opacity:.4
}
```

and the screenshot I took from Firefox: [screenshot](http://s17.postimg.org/hjri6s5mn/opacity.jpg)

It works perfectly as expected in any other browser that I've tested it with.

**EDIT**

Thanks to CairoCoder's reply, I accidentally found out that it only affected the images which size was reduced to fit the wrapping div.

So, opacity + reduced size are the two attributes that generate my issue.

I still have no idea why it behaves like that or if it's just my very own Firefox that is bugging.

**MOST IMPORTANTLY**
I don't want people to waste too much time on the subject. My main concern is to know if the issue is known, reproduced/reported and should be fixed or if it's just my Firefox acting weird. If no one has ever experienced that specific behaviour before - such as displayed on the screenshot - then I'll just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

*define* a div wrapper around image / slider elements with `max-height:` set and `overflow-x: hidden;` also give elements your styling [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) instead of using global `<div>` and `<a>` tags.

**Edit:**

**The root of this problem is where your images are coming from**; nothing else. You have no file types on them. I don't see a .jpg or .png etc. They seem to be populating somewhere dynamically as when I removed one, a different one appears. You also have two rows of 'images' with the exact same names, further proving my point. Please check these image paths, if you need to use actual images. Download them, host them locally be sure they are normal saved images with extentions .jpg etc defined, call them correctly, and your problem will be gone.

*But also adding the global tag usage when styling get's confusing especially using pseudo selectors and inheritance, this part just a suggestion.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not quite sure how it fixes it though, because the only issue I have is related to the opacity attribute and the odd behaviour it causes in my browser as shown on the screenshot, not the overflow nor the selectors. But then again, it might not even be a real bug but just a weird thing happening to me only

Comment: The images used are just common placeholders and are actual images. I experience the same problem when using local images with extension. I used the same rows/names in order to compare with and without opacity. I've tried to keep the code very simple just to target the one problem I have with opacity. All the rest should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to add extensions to images.

```
<div class="a">
<div><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-duniA1A1C0c/UXWqPdzXeCI/AAAAAAAAKio/Mj3DIbKXV7s/w126-h126-p/HD_beautiful_nature_landsacpe_2.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-IdeJ_2r_7hk/UJ9DtKJx0TI/AAAAAAAAFnw/sZ8FQ-8lGjE/w126-h126-p/fabulous-nature-scenery-25-photos-12.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--0CjkmkSU_8/U-DkyWhcX5I/AAAAAAAAIf8/hvpgW5UCnb0/w126-h126-p/Nature-0057.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-etqb2vA6RFg/T0Jmv2PtprI/AAAAAAAAEmY/Rz30YnMNX7E/w126-h126-p/Japanese+Nature+Picture+%2818%29.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Hf-iWqukw-w/UJ9Ds7xTYQI/AAAAAAAAFns/wNQ-2K9no-Y/w126-h126-p/fabulous-nature-scenery-25-photos-11.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<div class="b">
<div><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-duniA1A1C0c/UXWqPdzXeCI/AAAAAAAAKio/Mj3DIbKXV7s/w126-h126-p/HD_beautiful_nature_landsacpe_2.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-IdeJ_2r_7hk/UJ9DtKJx0TI/AAAAAAAAFnw/sZ8FQ-8lGjE/w126-h126-p/fabulous-nature-scenery-25-photos-12.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/--0CjkmkSU_8/U-DkyWhcX5I/AAAAAAAAIf8/hvpgW5UCnb0/w126-h126-p/Nature-0057.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-etqb2vA6RFg/T0Jmv2PtprI/AAAAAAAAEmY/Rz30YnMNX7E/w126-h126-p/Japanese+Nature+Picture+%2818%29.jpg" /></div>
<div><img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Hf-iWqukw-w/UJ9Ds7xTYQI/AAAAAAAAFns/wNQ-2K9no-Y/w126-h126-p/fabulous-nature-scenery-25-photos-11.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qk743u2/2/)

Comment: Thanks. The placeholding images I used are here for the example only and to save me some time but the extension shouldn't matter. I experienced the same problem with local files. 

But your example actually helped! When I first saw it, everything looked like it worked perfectly fine and I got very puzzled bc I knew it wasn't about the extension. But then when resizing the frame of the images and hence resizing the images themselves, the "thing" happened again. 

So now I can tell the problem is when images are styled with opacity AND reduced in size. I still have no idea why though!